# Firing WP action hook function from a different class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

In a custom plugin, I am creating a custom menu page in WP with an `admin_menu` hook in the main `Asset` loader class. In a separate file, I have another class called `Leads_UI` that houses the `public static function leads_html()` to output the markup to show on this custom admin page.

If you see in the code below, in the `register_leads_dashboard` function, if I am calling the
`leads_html` function via the same class rather than the `Leads_UI` class, it works as intended and outputs the html **only** when you are on that **Leads** page.

But if I try to use the `public static function leads_html()` from the separate `Leads_UI` class, `Leads_UI::leads_html()`, it is causing 2 errors:

1. The html is outputted on every page in the dashboard and shows at the top left corner behind the main content,
2. When I click on the 'Leads' page in dashboard, it throws the 404 page not found error.

What might be the issue? I am new to OOP.

```
namespace MWS_PLUGIN\Inc;

use MWS_PLUGIN\Inc\Traits\Singleton;

class Assets {

    use Singleton;

    protected function __construct() {
        // Load all critical functions
        $this->setup_hooks();
    }

    protected function setup_hooks() {
        //Add a new screen for 'Leads' CPT
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [$this, 'register_leads_dashboard'] );
    }

    public function register_leads_dashboard() {
        // This causes unexpected behaviour
        add_menu_page( __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), 'manage_options', 'leads-list', Leads_UI::leads_html(), 'dashicons-admin-users', 50 );

        // This works perfectly!
        //add_menu_page( __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), 'manage_options', 'leads-list', [ $this, 'leads_html' ], 'dashicons-admin-users', 50 );
    }

    public function leads_html() {
        esc_html_e( 'Leads page test', 'my-plugin' );
    }
}
```

`Lead_UI` class that's in a separate file:

```
namespace MWS_PLUGIN\Inc;
    
class Leads_UI {
        
    private function __construct(){
    }
        
    public static function leads_html() {
        esc_html_e( 'Leads page test', 'my-plugin' );
    }
}
```

[image: This is the html behind the content]

Comment: Ofcourse, I can take even the `admin_menu` hook to the `Leads_UI` class too, but is there a way to do it from the `Assets` class?

Comment: I think the issue may be caused by the way you are calling the leads_html() function of the Leads_UI class. Since the leads_html() function is defined as a static function, it should be called using the :: operator, as you mentioned in your code. try making the leads_html() function in the Leads_UI class static and self-contained, without any dependencies on other functions or properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [add_menu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) function's fifth parameter has the *callable* type.

But, your code doesn't pass the callable. Rather, it calls your void `Leads_UI::leads_html()` function, then passes the missing return value of that function to `add_menu_page()`. So the function is getting invoked at the time you call `add_menu_page()` which is not what you want.

```php
add_menu_page( __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), 
               'manage_options', 'leads-list',
               Leads_UI::leads_html(),         /* NOT a callable! */
               'dashicons-admin-users', 50 );
```

You want to specify that static function as a callable like this:

```
[ Leads_UI::class, 'leads_html' ]
```

giving code like this.

```php
add_menu_page( __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), __( 'Leads', 'my-plugin' ), 
               'manage_options', 'leads-list',
               [ Leads_UI::class, 'leads_html' ], /* Callable! */
               'dashicons-admin-users', 50 );
```

**Edit: More explanation**:

Here's the sequence of operations.

1. Somewhere in your code you say something like `new Assets()`.
2. That calls the `__construct` member function you showed us.
3. In turn that calls your `setup_hooks()` member function.
4. That registers an `admin_menu` action that will call your `register_leads_dashboard()` member function later on.
5. When you return from `__construct()`, WordPress does a whole lot of other stuff. If it's rendering any dashboard page, eventually it invokes your `admin_menu` action. If it's rendering a front-end page it never invokes it.
6. *Everything* that appears in the big dashboard menu on the left side of the dashboard, *everything*, is the result of some `admin_menu` action handler. There are *many* `admin_menu` handlers in WordPress. Yours is one of them.
7. WordPress calls your `admin_menu` handler which invokes your `register_leads_dashboard()` method.
8. You call `add_menu_page()` to put your **Leads** page on the menu.
9. That in turn registers another callback (the *callable* we've been talking about here) to be called when your user clicks on your menu item. In your case you want it to call that static member function `Leads_UI::leads_html()`.
10. When the user clicks on your menu item, WordPress calls that static member function.

WordPress lives, and sometimes dies (:-) by all these callbacks. And it happens that php has peculiar ways of declaring *callables*, the functions to be called when invoking callbacks.

1. For a global function, a callable is simply a text string containing its name.
2. For a non-static member function, the callable is

   ```php
   array( $instance, 'function_name' )
   ```
3. For a static member function like yours, the callable is

   ```php
   array( ClassName::class, 'function_name' )
   ```

Why not forget about all those class definitions and just make all callback functions global? Doing that would make it easier to add WordPress action and filter handlers. These reasons.

- Global name space pollution. If you and I both define the same global function namespace\name combination, the php program (WordPress) will crash. Using a static member function (what you did) is a way to take those functions out of the global namespace.
- Context. While an ordinary member function is running, it has access via `$this` to all the class instance's properties and functions. So one callback can save information in properties, and another callback can use that information.

Don't overthink this OOP stuff.

Comment: That works! Thanks, O. Jones. So if I understood it correctly, the moment `add_menu_page` was being called, which I believe is done on every dashboard page refresh to check if it is the 'Leads' page, so that's why `::leads_html()` was firing every time and since no container was being found it just left the echoed html lingering in the background, is that it?

Secondly, a `callable` means that this callback is defined but 'not' to be called immediately. Right? I want to understand this. OOP is so much fun!

Comment: Finally, as per codex and other media, in non-OOP environment, why does this work:
`function my_custom_menu_page(){
 esc_html_e( 'Admin Page Test', 'textdomain' ); 
}` 
right after the hook is called? I mean, that too is a basic function yes and not a callable? So this too should be invoked immediately when `add_menu_page()` is called?